# How to remove characters counting from the end of a string?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, irvine32

I have to remove a certain number of characters(let's say 3) from the end of a string. For this particular string it works when I find 'Z', and then make it point to W by sub edi, 3, and then storing the rest of the string with 0's.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
source BYTE "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0

.code
main PROC

mov edi, OFFSET source
mov al, 'Z'                  ; search for Z
mov ecx, LENGTHOF source
cld
repne scasb       ; repeat while not equal
sub edi, 3         ; now points to W

mov al, 0         
rep stosb        ; stores all characters after W with 0.

mov edx, OFFSET source
call WriteString
call CrlF

exit
main ENDP
end main
```

However, I want to make this code work with different null terminated strings. For that purpose I tried finding 0(the end of the string), as my code shows below. But it doesn't work, It just outputs the whole string.

What should I do to ensure that the code still works even if the string is changed without having to change the search for the end of the string every time?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
source BYTE "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0

.code
main PROC

mov edi, OFFSET source
mov al, '0'                  ; search for end of string
mov ecx, LENGTHOF source
cld
repne scasb       ; repeat while not equal
sub edi, 3         ; now points to W ??

mov al, 0         
rep stosb        ; stores all characters after W with 0.

mov edx, OFFSET source
call WriteString
call CrlF

exit
main ENDP
end main
```

Comment: You don't need to fill with zeroes, you just need one. For compile time constant strings you can just use the `LENGTHOF` as you did no need for any searching. Also note that `'0'` is the ascii code of `0` which is not `0` but `48` so that's not what you want.

Comment: At least one of your three attempts at this question didn't get closed. :)

Comment: My pleasure. It seems that this one more closely reflects what the "How to ask a question" wiki says to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you don't reset `ECX` with any value.

You set `ECX` to the length of the data, in this case 27. Then you find Z, which is the 26th value, so in the end `ECX` will have value `1` and your `rep stosb` will write one `0` in the string. Then you print it and that first nul will stop printing.

In the second one you're looking for `0` which is the last byte. Exiting the `repne scasb` `ECX` is zero, so `rep stosb` doesn't write anything.

To fix this you can use

```
mov edi, OFFSET source
mov al, 0                  ; search for end of string
mov ecx, LENGTHOF source
cld
repne scasb       ; repeat while not equal
sub edi, 3         ; now points to W ??

mov byte ptr [edi], 0     ; store a single nul since that's enough
```

Do note that in the first one *"stores all characters after W with 0"* is not true. You would have to do `ADD ECX, 3` after `SUB EDI, 3` to do that.

Do also note that `'0'` is the character 0, not the value 0.

Comment: For the second part replacing the mov al, 0 with mov edi, 0 still prints out the whole string.

Comment: @JoeDoe Note it's `MOV [EDI], 0`, not `MOV EDI, 0`. Actually there should be the data size also. So `MOV BYTE PTR [EDI], 0` so it stores the zero into the memory pointed by `EDI`, not into `EDI`.

Comment: It works now. Thanks. Thanks for the explanation in your answer too.